# flattened json file using javascript / coffee with d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, coffeescript

I am trying to flattened and combine value in json , here's the json

https://api.github.com/repos/wesm/D3py/commits

I have successfully extract by each position use this coffee code below

```
d3.json "https://api.github.com/repos/wesm/D3py/commits", (data) -> 
  console.log data[0].commit.author.name
  return
```

but when I tried to do something like here below I expected to see array of name , but got nothing ,

```
 d3.json "https://api.github.com/repos/wesm/D3py/commits", (data) -> 
  names = (name for name in data.commit.author.name)
  console.log names
  return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = (entry.commit.author.name for entry in data)
```

Comment: Thank you ! @meetamit this works great , it took me 3 hours !!